# XAMLParseException Occurs during build.

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm building a WP8 Application for a project, which basically imports an XML file from the web and displays the content in a LongListSelector.

Here is my XAML Code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lb_country_list"
                                LayoutMode="List"
                                IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                                HideEmptyGroups ="true"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Height="655"
                                Margin="10,10,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Width="436"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LLSItemTemplate}"/>

        <Button Content="Get Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="88" Margin="125,670,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="221"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LLSItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Margin="10"
                           Text="{Binding country_namef}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           Foreground="Black"/>
                <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="0" X2="480" Y1="0" Y2="0" Stroke="Gray" Margin="0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>



</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I get the following Error.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Additional information: Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key LLSItemTemplate [Line: 32 Position: 50]
```

at my InitializeComponent() in MainPage.xaml.vb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional information says exactly what's wrong: the parser cannot find the resource `LLSItemTemplate`. You should include the itemtemplate of the `LongListSelector` in `MainPage.xaml` or in `App.xaml`.

Comment: Tutorials on the net are outdated I guess. They instructed to create the <phone:ApplicationPage.Resources> and put the templates there.

I didn't include the itemtemplate in the mainpage.xaml or app.xaml but put it within the longlistselector tags using the <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate> tag.

Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Well, I don't think the tutorials are outdated. I missed something in your question. I just saw that the template isn't missing but it is in the wrong location. Templates should appear immediately after the opening `PhoneApplicationPage` tag. I tried your code, moved the template to the appropriate position and it works like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that a while back.